# Transform complex CAD (no blockreference) objects to line in CAD to GIS workflow

Tags: qgis, fme-form

I have a CAD file with a lot of details in it. For example i have doors that are made up from like 50 very fine grained lines, including handle and opening radius.

I don't need this level of detail and would like to replace it with a single line representing the door.

In a generalised form my question is, is there a way to replace complex objects in a CAD to GIS workflow with simple geometries?

Added complexity arises from the fact that the orientation of the input object can change.

[image]

My ultimate goal is to replace the horizontal doors with simple lines.

Comment: I'm curious to know what solutions are out there too. My experience so far (with architectural/survey drawings) is that it's far faster/easier to simplify the geometries in a CAD program - including merging layers, standardising line styles - than to do it in a GIS program.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Could you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of what you have and what you'd like to have. I'm certain you can leverage FME to transform your ulines to a more simplified geometry. But without knowing what you are trying to achieve, exactly, it's difficult to answer the question.

Comment: If the doors are autocad_blocks, just replace the block by another geometry. They will have a rotation as well so orientation should not be a problem.
If the doors are exploded blocks in the cad file there is not an easy way. Generic solutions are often not good enough for this kind of specific questions.
I would never try to do it in CAD software as it is a lot of work which can be easy done repetitive with an FME workspace.

Comment: They are not blocks, thats my problem. Can you please elaborate how you would tackle this problem with FME ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked in cadastre preparation in both CAD and GIS era.

I simply imported the data into GIS and selected the data that I didn't need, like window_panes or ..., via select by attributes(because they were on different layers) and delete them.

but in your case, you have to group those fine lines first.

I didn't test it in AutoCAD but I think for this kind of operations Microstation is preferred.

you can also symbolize the detailed layer in QGIS with lots of options either(like fading them)...